# Need help to resolve a slider javascript conflict with Safari

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm facing a problem with a slider that I'm using on a website. 
([www.cloosedesign.com](http://www.cloosedesign.com))
The website is a portfolio I made for a friend. So there are severals works to show. 
Each work is listed as a link, and when you click on the link it shows you the corresponding picture with the slider. (I've put some PHP to get the right pictures from the database Mysql).

It works fine, except on SAFARI. Indeed sometimes when I click on a link the text of the footer (white text on the black box) desappear and re-appear, like if the page was refreshing.
This pb appear sometimes after the 3rd click, or sometimes after more clicks.

here is my code :

in the `<head>` : 
I'm calling jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And I'm calling the javascript file for the slider :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
```

then in the portfolio_english page I'm checking the images corresponding to the work selected (= $contenu):

```
<?
        $images_sql = "SELECT * FROM `a_fichier`
                WHERE id_fiche=".$contenu."
                    ORDER BY tri";
        $images = mysql_query($images_sql);

        echo'<div id="slides">';
        echo '<div class="slides_container">';

        while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
            {
            echo "<img src='Images/PorteDoc2/".$image['nom']."' width='540' height='600' alt='".$image['titre']."' />"; 
            }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>'; ?>
```

And just after the php code I write the following javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage:'Images/img/loading.gif',
        pagination: true,
        fadeSpeed: 0,
        slideSpeed: 0,
        effect: 'slide, slide',
    });
});
</script>
```

And then I call the footer.php file.
Thanks

Comment: Could you may be make a jsfiddle to explain your problem a bit better, I can't click any links on the website listed above (the language barrier isn't helping a lot either :P)

Comment: Hi Lenny, if you want to switch the website to english you have a link on the top right of the page. The problem that I'm facing is that when you go on the portfolio page of the site, and then when you click on the links that are on the left of this page, 2 pbs appear : the text of the footer desappear and reappear, and the whole page "flash". These pbs don't appear after each click. Sometimes after the second click, sometimes after 15 clicks. And it only appear on Safari. Is that more clear ? Please don't hesitate to  tell me if it is not. Thank you !

Comment: When you say footer are you reffering to big black box at the end of the page? And I think the reason why the page is flashing (if I understand you) is simply because you are loading a new page, and safari seems to be slower in rendering...

Comment: hi Lenny, yes the footer is the black box at the end with the white text written on it. After some clicks on the links (on the left column of the portfolio's page) part of the text of the footer disappear and appear again (it is fast but with big screens where you see the whole page it is tiring). Concerning the page that flash I see your point, but now I think this pb is fixed as it is not flshing anymore... but there is still the text of the footer that bugs... Thanks Lenny –

Comment: The flashing in the footer is also due to the page refreshing, as far as I can tell on my version of safari (mac), I have to zoom out to see the footer and the links at the side, so the footer shouldn't be that much of a hassle anyway, because there aren't that many people that have a 32 inch flatscreen as there monitor :P, for them that do, you should look into ajax to dynamically load the images into the page, if you want I will give you a jsfiddle demonstrating what I mean.

Comment: ok, in fact my friend for whom I did this site has a 27-inch imac, and that mean that she saw the whole page without having to zoom out ... it's no luck for me ;-)) So yes please if you have an example for me to dynamically load the images into the page... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This http://jsfiddle.net/NNSqw/ is the code that does what I mean, it uses jquery and ajax, now, to explain the html bit is pretty straight forward the div with the `id="content"` will be where your content will get loaded into.

Now to the JS/JQuery, everytime a user presses a link the content of the div with the `id="content"` gets changed, you will have to make a page named get_images.php and make it use the php code `$_GET['realisation'];` to get the number of the link clicked and from there it will work like your current page :).

Sorry I'm not brilliant at explaining but, if you wish me to try and clarify it more just say :)

**Edit:**

Right in your **portfolio_english.php** file the following code should exists (I'm using the english version of your site):

```
<span class="link" onClick="javascript: show_image('1')">Entreprise internationale    1</span><br>
<span class="link" onClick="javascript: show_image('2')">Entreprise internationale 2</span><br>
<span class="link" onClick="javascript: show_image('3')">Entreprise internationale 3</span><br>
<span class="link" onClick="javascript: show_image('4')">Entreprise internationale 4</span>
```

You should have your links that the side, which have an onClick event leading them to the javascript function which should be in the head of the page:

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         show_image(no){
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'get_images.php?realisation='+no,
             success: function(data) {
                 $('#content').html(data);
            }
          });
         }
     </script>
    [... rest of header ...]
    </head>
```

Also in that file you should have the div where the images currently appear

```
<div id="content">

</div>​
```

**get_image.php**

In your get_image.php you need to have what you currently use to get your images, so to get the number e.g. 41 into the php code you are using use:

```
<?php
$number = $_GET['realisation'];
[... Rest of php code to retrieve images ...]
?>
```

Also, if you still don't understand where I'm going try reading the jquery documentation to see if you understand it more then: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks for the explanation ;-) So if I understood well I have to copy the Ajax code in the <head>. Then to add a <div id="content"> in my "realisation.php" page. I'll also have to take out of this page the php code to get the images, and to paste it in a new page "get_images.php". I'll add the css for the div. Then I'm a little lost: I've to link "realisation.php" and "get_images.php" ? Do I have to add something else in these pages ? Thanks :-)

Comment: I don't think you've missed anything out... just make sure, that you have jquery link in your head and make sure to link up the buttons at the side to the ajax code which is in the head, it should all fit into place then

Comment: Ok I see where you are going, but I don't have the same code as what you have written. I've updated my question with my code so you will see that.

Comment: show_image() is a javascript function, when the user clicks the link the javascript function show_image() gets called. The reason there is a number in the show_image() onClick event in the span tag is the image number, so this will depend on which picture you would like to load, I would want to give you a more acurate demo, but I don't have anyway to upload it :(, I hope this helps you more

Comment: ok I understand, but the javascript file that I use for the slider doesn't use show_image function. Well as I might have found yourself I'm new with javascript ;-) , and the file for the slider is quite complex for me to understand. But I think there must be a function that do the same as show_image() as the slider shows the right images. You tell me but I see 2 possibilities. The 1st one if you want I can send you the js file for you to see. The 2nd is that I'll try to replace the actual slider and the js file by the show_image function... What do you think is the best way ? Thanks again :-)

Comment: If, you are willing to wait till tomorrow (quite late where I am now) I am new to github but I will try to upload some files to show you exactly what your system should look like, javascript function show_image() is what you copy and paste (from the code above) into your portfolio_english.php ... What you could also try and do is zip up the whole web directory folder and send it via email to me and I can have a look at the full code, either way I don't mind, but it will have to wait till tomorrow :( (my email is in my profile page I think)

Comment: ok really nice from you :-).
No pbs for me to wait for tomorrow. I'll appreciate to look to your files to learn new things :-).
And also I'll send you my files so you'll see my code (php, js...). I just checked your profile but I didn't find your email. 
So talk to you tomorrow :-)

Comment: I would like to thank Lenny for his help and time as he helped me to figured out where the bug was and how to deal with it. THANK YOU Lenny ! :-))))

Answer (score 0):

OK, before any real investigation let's get a few things out of the way.

1. Update jQuery to the newest version (http://jquery.com/), then you don't need the easing plugin as it's built in nowadays.
2. Rather than bind to window.onload, use the proper syntax for using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage:'Images/img/loading.gif',
        pagination: true,
        fadeSpeed: 0,
        slideSpeed: 0,
        effect: 'slide, slide',
    });
});
```

If that isn't any good, make a really small test page that only has the code you are using with the slider, and check if it's still a problem.

To be honest, I don't really know why people use these massive slider plugins, making a slider is an easy little job that requires less than 10 lines of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advices Rich ! I'll try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi Rich. the bugs on the footer is still there... I hope I'm not abusing of your time but have you other suggestions that might help me ? Thanks again for your help and your time.

Comment: I'm actually going away for a few days, so probably won't have a chance to look properly. I can't see this bug anywhere though, so perhaps the newer version of Safari has fixed this.

Comment: Also, I still can't actually find the slider on the page! The only bit I've found just changes from one image to another. If there is a slider, then the flash will likely be when Safari changes from 2d to 3d context to get faster animations. That's been fixed on newer builds, so I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Ok thanks Rich. The slider is on the portfolio page, and as you said it is used to show some images corresponding of the works on which you click. Thanks.